# centos 8 Dockerfile apache http2

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, docker, http2

I'm trying to dockerise our system and I'm doing it step by step with 2 servers.

In one I have docker (running on a centos7 server) and in the internal dev VM (running Centos8) I'm installing the same software as in the Dockerfile.

I'm trying to install Apache in HTTP2 and by this [guide](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-apache-with-ssl-http2-on-rhel-centos/) if I run `sudo yum install @httpd` it should install apache with HTTP2 module, though in the Docker image I cannot install it. Any ideas?

if I connect to the docker container and I run `yum install httpd` say that is already installed and with `yum install @hhtpd` it say `group httpd not found`
the version installed in the official image doesn't have the http2 module

I'm using `FROM centos:8` in the dockerfile
this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:8

RUN yum -y update && yum -y install gzip libjpeg-devel libtiff-devel libpng-devel \
    freetype-devel httpd-devel byacc flex ksh sysstat sqlite-devel libjpeg \
    sqlite-devel cmake pixman pixman-devel gcc gcc-c++ curl-devel gd-devel \
    giflib-devel libxml2-devel automake autoconf libtool make wget zip unzip @httpd

...
continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using @httpd you can try to install all the components individually:

```
FROM centos:8

RUN yum -y update && yum -y install gzip libjpeg-devel libtiff-devel libpng-devel \
    freetype-devel httpd-devel byacc flex ksh sysstat sqlite-devel libjpeg \
    sqlite-devel cmake pixman pixman-devel gcc gcc-c++ curl-devel gd-devel \
    giflib-devel libxml2-devel automake autoconf libtool make wget zip unzip \
    httpd httpd-filesystem httpd-tools mod_http2 mod_ssl
```

Comment: seems to be working but the `mod_http2.so` file is not present in the system

Comment: The package mod_http2 is installed? [In these web](https://rm-rf.es/instalar-apache-httpd-rhel-8-centos-8/) you could see an example of installation of HTTPD and see that mod_http2 is installed like a dependency. You can use `$ rpm -qa | grep http` to check it. Also you can try to find the file in the system with `$ sudo find / -name mod_http2.so`

Comment: I removed the image and compile it again from 0 and now seems to be working correctly.